# Python 2.7 Gmail API - How do I bypass the consent screen ("Request for Permission")

Tags: python, api, permissions, gmail

I'm working with the Gmail API for Python 2.7. As part of an automated solution, I am trying to send emails from my personal Gmail account to a specified list of recipients. My code will be kicked off via a `.bat` file at set intervals of time (for example, every 30 minutes).

The problem: Every time I run the code, a `consent screen` pops up via the default web browser and asks me to "Allow" access (see image below). I read in the Gmail API documentation that you can add parameters to the `client_secret.json` file.

Some of those parameters are "prompt", "approval_prompt", "access_type", etc. I found a page that had all of these parameters within it, but can't seem to locate it again within the Gmail API documentation. I would think that appropriately setting one of these parameters would give me what I'm looking for.

Could someone help with finding a way to bypass this consent screen altogether and simply set the default to "Allow" access so that I don't have to manually click "Allow" every time my code runs?

Thanks in advance!